# iOS - Set ImageView background color and mask

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview

How can I set the background color of an ImageView for an icon and have it mask to bounds? So that the inner transparent parts of the image are then the background color?

Example: in this twitter icon, how can I set the inner white (transparent) parts of the icon to be a different color?

EDIT: What if the image is NOT a circle? But any shape.

[image]

Comment: set backgroundColor, corner radius and mask to bounds.

Comment: check my updated answer if it is what you want

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the following steps

```
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImageName")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 14 //number of your choice
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.tintColor = .black
```

Comment: I think that setting the rendering mode is not needed

Comment: what if the image is not a circle

Comment: As Phyber suggested you can have any value here , if you dont want the round corners or a circle you can give cornerRadius as 0

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.backgroundColor = .blue //Sets the background color
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.width/2   //Crops the image to be a circle
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true //Sets the mask to bounds
```

If you want a custom shape you can do this:

- create two imageViews (above each other)
- first imageView use as usual
- second imageView use as background shape

Code for the one in foreground

```
firstImageView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Second imageView (in the background)

```
secondImageView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
secondImageView.tintColor = yourBackgroundColor
secondImageView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Comment: but what if it is not a circle

Comment: You can set whatever corner radius you want.

Comment: But if you want custom shape you can use two images. One for the shape and background and one for the foreground.